# Simple step in time evolution of position operator in simple harmonic motion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

When considering the 'Heisenberg' picture of the harmonic oscillator, I've come across the step:
$$\begin{align}
\left\langle n\left|(\hat{q_H}\hat{H}-\hat{H}\hat{q_H})\right|k\right\rangle &= (E_k-E_n)q_{nk}
\end{align}$$

where $\hat{q_H}$ is a position operator. I realise that this must be a pretty simple step for someone who is familiar with Dirac notation, but I'm not sure how the author has *unlocked* the $\hat{H}$ from the $\hat{H}\hat{q_H}$?

Any comments greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamiltonian can act on the left or on the right state vector.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. Somewhat surprisingly, I'm sure that this is the first time I've heard that :s. What is the motivation for an operator acting 'backwards'?

Comment: In a scalar product $(\psi_1,\hat{H}\psi_2)$ there are two state vectors. There is a definition of a conjugate operator: it is another operator and it acts on the other state vector, like this: $(\hat{H}^+\psi_1,\psi_2)=(\psi_1,\hat{H}\psi_2)$. The conjugate operator $\hat{H}^+$ is not obliged to be the same as $\hat{H}$, it may even not exists at all. But for a Hamiltonian the conjugate operator coincides with its the original Hamiltonian and this gives the eigenvalue of the original Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used the adjoint of operators before, but I wasn't sure about the rigour of applying the operation to parts of a two operator product like $\hat{H}\hat{q_h}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\left\langle n\left|\hat{q_H}\hat{H}-\hat{H}\hat{q_H}\right|k\right\rangle 
&= \left\langle n\left|\hat{q_H}\hat{H}\right|k\right\rangle 
-\left\langle n\left|\hat{H}\hat{q_H}\right|k\right\rangle\\
&= E_k\left\langle n\left|\hat{q_H}\right|k\right\rangle 
-E_n\left\langle n\left|\hat{q_H}\right|k\right\rangle\\
&= (E_k-E_n)\left\langle n\left|\hat{q_H}\right|k\right\rangle\\
&\equiv (E_k-E_n)q_{nk}
\end{align}$$